# Parse id from javascript

Tags: javascript, parsing

I have html code considering this(example):

```
$(window).ready(function () {
    video.search.apply_results({
        "scope":"global",
        "global":{
            "list":[{
                "id":19366,
                "user_id":null,
                "title":"\u041c\u043e\u0440\u0441\u043a\u0430\u044f \u0418\u0441\u0442\u043e\u0440\u0438\u044f: \u0422\u043e, \u0447\u0442\u043e \u0432 \u0442\u0432\u043e\u0438\u0445 \u0441\u0438\u043b\u0430\u0445 \/ Umi Monogatari: Anata ga Ite [hl]Kureta[\/hl] Koto (RUS) \u0421\u0435\u0440\u0438\u044f \u21161",
                "thumb_url":"http:\/\/cs1.premedias.ru\/videos\/1\/9\/3\/6\/6\/6982b758bb030f4075d40696433158ef_s.jpg",
                "duration":1453,
                "description":"\u0414\u0432\u0435 \u0441\u0435\u0441\u0442\u0440\u044b-\u0440\u0443\u0441\u0430\u043b\u043a\u0438 \u041c\u0430\u0440\u0438\u043d \u0438 \u0423\u0440\u0438\u043d \u0436\u0438\u0432\u0443\u0442 \u0432 \u043e\u043a\u0435\u0430\u043d\u0441\u043a\u0438\u0445 \u0433\u043b\u0443\u0431\u0438\u043d\u0430\u0445, \u043e\u0431\u0449\u0430\u044e\u0442\u0441\u044f \u0441 \u0440\u043e\u0434\u0438\u0447\u0430\u043c\u0438, \u0430 \u0442\u0430\u043a\u0436\u0435 \u0441 \u0440\u044b\u0431\u0430\u043c\u0438, \u0447...",
                "is_hd":true
            },{
                "id":19367,
                "user_id":null,
                "title":"\u041c\u043e\u0440\u0441\u043a\u0430\u044f \u0418\u0441\u0442\u043e\u0440\u0438\u044f: \u0422\u043e, \u0447\u0442\u043e \u0432 \u0442\u0432\u043e\u0438\u0445 \u0441\u0438\u043b\u0430\u0445 \/ Umi Monogatari: Anata ga Ite [hl]Kureta[\/hl] Koto (RUS) \u0421\u0435\u0440\u0438\u044f \u21162",
                "thumb_url":"http:\/\/cs1.premedias.ru\/videos\/1\/9\/3\/6\/7\/d2dc60de1ec00f944e74b2aa1f6db942_s.jpg",
                "duration":1454,
                "description":"\u0414\u0432\u0435 \u0441\u0435\u0441\u0442\u0440\u044b-\u0440\u0443\u0441\u0430\u043b\u043a\u0438 \u041c\u0430\u0440\u0438\u043d \u0438 \u0423\u0440\u0438\u043d \u0436\u0438\u0432\u0443\u0442 \u0432 \u043e\u043a\u0435\u0430\u043d\u0441\u043a\u0438\u0445 \u0433\u043b\u0443\u0431\u0438\u043d\u0430\u0445, \u043e\u0431\u0449\u0430\u044e\u0442\u0441\u044f \u0441 \u0440\u043e\u0434\u0438\u0447\u0430\u043c\u0438, \u0430 \u0442\u0430\u043a\u0436\u0435 \u0441 \u0440\u044b\u0431\u0430\u043c\u0438, \u0447...",
                "is_hd":true
            }],
            "count":28
        }
    });
});
```

I need to echo the number going after first "id":, in this example it is 19366. How could I do it using javascript?

Comment: Do you need to do it inside apply_results function or outside of context, treating html above as plain text?

Comment: What is the `apply_results` function? Where is this data actually stored?

Comment: I get this data from some url.

Comment: The title could use some editing to show this is not about parsing ids in general.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're writing the `apply_results` function and it looks kinda like this:

```
function apply_results(opts) {
    // ...
    // alerts first id
    alert(opts.global.list[0].id);
}
```

And if you just get html above as text, and you want to pull the id from it, use following regexp:

```
// assuming text holds all the html OP pasted following alerts first id found
alert(text.match(/\"id\":(\d+)/)[1]);
```

Comment: Thanks! And how could I get all my code from another page? This code I get from http://site1.com and I need to echo id on site2.com.

Answer (score 1):

There's no (further) *parsing* required. Once you have that data from whatever source it was, based on your quoted code it's already been deserialized (parsed) into an object graph. You just refer to that object graph's `global.list[0].id`. For instance:

```
$(window).ready(function () {
    var results = {
        "scope": "global",
        "global": {
            "list": [{
                "id": 19366,
                "user_id": null,
                "title": "\u041c\u043e\u0440\u0441\u043a\u0430\u044f \u0418\u0441\u0442\u043e\u0440\u0438\u044f: \u0422\u043e, \u0447\u0442\u043e \u0432 \u0442\u0432\u043e\u0438\u0445 \u0441\u0438\u043b\u0430\u0445 \/ Umi Monogatari: Anata ga Ite [hl]Kureta[\/hl] Koto (RUS) \u0421\u0435\u0440\u0438\u044f \u21161",
                "thumb_url": "http:\/\/cs1.premedias.ru\/videos\/1\/9\/3\/6\/6\/6982b758bb030f4075d40696433158ef_s.jpg",
                "duration": 1453,
                "description": "\u0414\u0432\u0435 \u0441\u0435\u0441\u0442\u0440\u044b-\u0440\u0443\u0441\u0430\u043b\u043a\u0438 \u041c\u0430\u0440\u0438\u043d \u0438 \u0423\u0440\u0438\u043d \u0436\u0438\u0432\u0443\u0442 \u0432 \u043e\u043a\u0435\u0430\u043d\u0441\u043a\u0438\u0445 \u0433\u043b\u0443\u0431\u0438\u043d\u0430\u0445, \u043e\u0431\u0449\u0430\u044e\u0442\u0441\u044f \u0441 \u0440\u043e\u0434\u0438\u0447\u0430\u043c\u0438, \u0430 \u0442\u0430\u043a\u0436\u0435 \u0441 \u0440\u044b\u0431\u0430\u043c\u0438, \u0447...",
                "is_hd": true
            }, {
                "id": 19367,
                "user_id": null,
                "title": "\u041c\u043e\u0440\u0441\u043a\u0430\u044f \u0418\u0441\u0442\u043e\u0440\u0438\u044f: \u0422\u043e, \u0447\u0442\u043e \u0432 \u0442\u0432\u043e\u0438\u0445 \u0441\u0438\u043b\u0430\u0445 \/ Umi Monogatari: Anata ga Ite [hl]Kureta[\/hl] Koto (RUS) \u0421\u0435\u0440\u0438\u044f \u21162",
                "thumb_url": "http:\/\/cs1.premedias.ru\/videos\/1\/9\/3\/6\/7\/d2dc60de1ec00f944e74b2aa1f6db942_s.jpg",
                "duration": 1454,
                "description": "\u0414\u0432\u0435 \u0441\u0435\u0441\u0442\u0440\u044b-\u0440\u0443\u0441\u0430\u043b\u043a\u0438 \u041c\u0430\u0440\u0438\u043d \u0438 \u0423\u0440\u0438\u043d \u0436\u0438\u0432\u0443\u0442 \u0432 \u043e\u043a\u0435\u0430\u043d\u0441\u043a\u0438\u0445 \u0433\u043b\u0443\u0431\u0438\u043d\u0430\u0445, \u043e\u0431\u0449\u0430\u044e\u0442\u0441\u044f \u0441 \u0440\u043e\u0434\u0438\u0447\u0430\u043c\u0438, \u0430 \u0442\u0430\u043a\u0436\u0435 \u0441 \u0440\u044b\u0431\u0430\u043c\u0438, \u0447...",
                "is_hd": true
            }],
            "count": 28
        }
    };
    video.search.apply_results(results);
    console.log(results.global.list[0].id);
});
```

All I did above was move the massive object literal you were passing into `apply_results` to a variable (`results`), use that variable with `apply_results`, and then show the first `id` value (`results.global.list[0].id`). And formatted the code. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use array projection method .map()

```
var ids = json.global.list.map(function(i){
  return i.id;
});

console.log(ids);//[19366, 19367]
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you want precisely! By the way, I've imagined a situation like this:

```
<video id="id19367"/>
<video id="19367"/>​
```

however, once you find the id, you can use replace() javascript function to "remove" 'id'.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var ids = new Array();
  $('video').each(function() {
     var id = $(this).attr('id');  
      if(id[0]=='i') {
          var toRemove = 'id';
          id = id.replace(toRemove,'');
      }
      ids.push(id);    
      console.log(id);          
  });
});​
```